# Should I be calling the set length method in the method itself?

Tags: java

My assignment prompt states:

> Create a class MP3 with instance variables for: artist, song, album, track length (in seconds). Provide a constructor with four parameters, get/set methods, and a toString. method. The toString method should return a String with MP3 data clearly labeled. The track length should be converted into minutes and seconds in the toString method. For example, 265 seconds would be displayed as 4:25. NOTE that an MP3 cannot have a zero or negative track length. Use the default value of one minute for an invalid track length.

I am confused with the last sentence of those instructions. Can someone explain it to me?

I have this code so far:

```
public class MP3 {

    private String artist;
    private String song;
    private String album;
    private int trackLength;

    public MP3(String artistName, String songName, String albumName, int lengthOfTrack) {
        setArtist(artistName);
        setSong(songName);
        setAlbum(albumName);
        setLength(lengthOfTrack);
    }

    public void setArtist(String artistName) {
        artist = artistName;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setSong(String songName) {
        song = songName;
    }

    public String getSong() {
        return song;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String albumName) {
        album = albumName;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setLength(int lengthOfTrack) {
        trackLength = lengthOfTrack;

         if(getLength() <= 0) {
                setLength(60);
            }
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return trackLength;  
    }

    public String toString() {

        return String.format("%s, %s, %s, %d : %d",
            getArtist(), getSong(), getAlbum(),
            getLength() / 60, getLength() - (getLength() / 60) * 60); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I mean, you could do it non-recursively, but it's not a problem to do it that way.

Comment: Well, given your code, I think you have understood it perfectly. Why do you think you haven't?

Comment: I read that as meaning "If the track length they give you is garbage (ex. -0:37, 0:00, or haha), use 1:00".

Comment: Oh wait, you want to use `if(lengthOfTrack <= 0)` not `if(getLength() <= 0)`.

Comment: @EliSadoff `getLength()` returns `trackLength`

Comment: @cricket_007 You're right. This code is fine.

Comment: This question, while well intended, is primarily opinion based so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @JBNizet I was wondering if it would be redundant to call the setLength method in side the method itself and by the responses Im assuming the answer is yes:) however Im still not sure how to write it a better way.

Comment: I have posted an answer showing you a better way.

Answer (score 0):

No, in a normal scenario that would lead to recursion until a [`StackOverflowException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) occurs, not in your case since on the next call you would exit the recursion. In general you should avoid using recursion if you don't need do.

You can simply modify the value before setting it, eg:

```
public void setLength(int trackLength) {
  if (trackLength <= 0)
    trackLength = 60;

  this.trackLength = trackLength;
}
```

Comment: Why would it lead to a StackOverflowError?

Comment: I don't agree that recursion is to be avoided. Recursion can be wonderful and efficient as long as it is tail recursive.

Comment: @EliSadoff: recursion is a tool that must be used when you decide to use it, not as a side effect of your code, which is clearly what's happening here.

Comment: How is this a side effect of the code? Additionally, this won't lead to a `StackOverflowException`. `getLength()` is set before it is checked so everything works.

Comment: @EliSadoff: it's a side effect since the OP didn't want to explicitly use recursion, it just happens to be used, so it's a side effect under all effects. I'm not against recursion, I perfectly know how wonderful it can be (and how you can solve complex things in a bunch of lines of code) but having a setter which invokes itself is not a good practice unless you know why you are doing it.

Comment: Shouldn't the variable in the parameter say lengthOfTrack?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

- you did implement the requirement correctly (as in, it works)
- your implementation is convoluted, though, and uses bad practices: using recursion when not needed, calling overridable methods from the constructor, changing the field to an invalid value, and change it right after
- Ignoring the value passed in the constructor/setter and replacing it by a default value is bad practice, too: an exception should be thrown instead. But that's what your teacher asked, so you can't do much about it.

Here's how I would implement it:

```
public class MP3 {

    private String artist;
    private String song;
    private String album;
    private int trackLength;

    public MP3(String artist, String song, String album, int trackLength) {
        this.artist = artist;
        this.song = song;
        this.album = album;
        this.trackLength = trackLengthOrDefault(trackLength);
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getSong() {
        return song;
    }

    public void setSong(String song) {
        this.song = song;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        this.album = album;
    }

    public int getTrackLength() {
        return trackLength;
    }

    public void setTrackLength(int trackLength) {
        this.trackLength = trackLengthOrDefault(trackLength);
    }

    private int trackLengthOrDefault(int length) {
        return length <= 0 ? 60 : length;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s, %s, %s, %d:%d",
            artist, song, album, trackLength / 60, trackLength % 60);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you. Considering yesterday was the first day I've heard about recursion:)

Comment: How would you expand the statement `return length <= 0 ? 60 : length;` ?

Comment: If the length is <= 0, then returns 60, otherwise return the length.

Answer (score -1):

"Use the default value of one minute for an invalid track length"

If you are not told a track length, it should be set to 60.  So

`private int trackLength = 60`;

Then all your setter needs to check if whether the incoming value is positive.  Not too different from other answer, really

Comment: There is no way to avoid setting a track length, since the only constructor has it as argument. So initializing the field to 60 is useless.

Comment: @JBNizet You could have `if (lengthOfTrack > 0)` in as a condition in the constructor.

Comment: The OP already has that, indirectly, by having it in the setter called by the constructor. I wouldn't code it the same way as the OP did, but he did implement what the sentence asked. And just setting the field to 60 won't help, to the contrary.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree. I was merely pointing out a way you could theoretically use a default field value in this scenario.

Comment: @JBNizet could you explain how I could do it more directly?